# MySQL Workbench Server Status graphs have no data

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL workbench for a couple of different connections on different servers. On one of my servers I go to the "Server Status" page and I am unable to see any data on the graphs. It shows the following:

[image]

Does anyone know why I always get "No Data"? The mysql user I'm connecting with has every mysql privilege.

Comment: This usually happens if MySQL Workbench doesn't know how to retrieve the data or if there's a problem. Check the log file if there's anything that hints at the cause (Help -> Show Log File).

Comment: I basically get nothing from the log. When I monitor the log and click on Server Status I get the following: 16:03:01 [INF][wb_admin_control.py:server_polling_thread:540]: Monitoring thread running...